# What do you do inspiring yourself in Christmas

Tags: discussion

First I want to wish you all a Merry Christmas.

While our homes, workplaces and streets are decorated to welcome the Christmas and the end of the year some of the designers I know like to decorate their PC not only by changing the OS themes but also the outside frame of their monitors to get deep into the Christmas mood. :)

I would like to know if you are involved doing a design that might have a Christmas theme/decoration or related to the season, like greeting cards, wallpapers and present wraps. What is the first thought to start your project? I don't want to mimic the traditional assets and I want to start from my own point of view.

Your experience is very appreciated and once again Merry Christmas and Happy New Year.

Comment: Just curious but why did you post this on meta instead of the original site?

Comment: @Darth_Vader .. if you see it is eligible to the main site so please post it there if you cloud. be my guess :)

Comment: I did post it here to not exclude my Christmas wish. the main site is more that a serious site :\ and thanks for the editing.

Comment: Well the issue it isn't really a good fit there or here.  This question is opinionated and is looking for suggestive answers and not actual answers to a question.  Plus, answers to this question over time will change because everyone will have their own opinion.  Something like this would be better suited in a chat.

Comment: You have enough rep, why not remove this and create a chatroom?  Wait for others on the network chime in.

Comment: This question is essentially "how do you brainstorm ideas" which I believe we've covered more than a few times already. I'd search for 'brainstorming'.